# css transition and jquery animation conflict

Tags: jquery, css

I use the following css code to put transition in all my site

```
*{
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
transition: all 0.3s ease;}
```

In part of the site, i have a title and when click in it must show the hidden content. In this case i use the following jquery code.

```
jQuery(".title").click(function () {

    jQuery(".content").slideToggle(300);

});
```

the opening animation is not smoothly

I put a code example here
https://jsfiddle.net/304u3ogv/

Someone know why happen this stuck effect?

P.S.: sorry about my bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `transition: none;` to `#content` in the CSS

See this updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/304u3ogv/1/

Comment: it is better approach than my answer , just removed mine

Comment: simply and nice answer, works for me, thanks. For curiosity (and dont know why) i put `transition: all 0.03s ;` and works too.

Comment: jQuery `toggleSlide` adds inline styles such as `height`, `padding`, `margin`, to the toggled element therefore all of these properties are transitioned for 0.3s but jQuery is trying to update the values of these at the same time.
So by removing this transition `transition: none` or `transition: all 0.03s;` (which is essentially `transition: all 0s;`) we let jQuery, not the CSS, handle the transitions